# facebookexternalhit/1.1 bot Excessive Requests, Need to Slow Down

Tags: woocommerce

facebookexternalhit/1.1 hitting my WooCommerce site badly, causing 503 error. So many requests per second. I tried to slow it down using robot txt and set wordfence rate limit. Nothing works, is there any way to slow down without blocking the bot?

Here's few example of raw access logs.

> GET /item/31117/x HTTP/1.0" 301 - "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1
> (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)   GET
> /?post_type=cms_block&p=311 HTTP/1.0" 503 607 "-"
> "facebookexternalhit/1.1
>
> GET /item/31117/xiaomi-redmi-router HTTP/1.1" 200 48984 "-"

Answer (score 2):

If someone shares a link to your site on Facebook, on occasion when someone views the link (on Facebook, they don't have to click it), Facebook will reach out and grab the rich embed data (opengraph image etc..).  This is a very well known problem if you search around the net.

The solution is to rate limit any useragent containing this text:
facebookexternalhit

The crawler does not respect robots.txt and it can actually be leveraged in DDOS attacks, there are many articles about it:

https://thehackernews.com/2014/04/vulnerability-allows-anyone-to-ddos.html
https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/facebook-exploit-is-not-unique

They do not respect robots.txt so you have to rate limit.  I'm not familiar with Woocommerce but you can search for "Apache rate limiting" or "nginx rate limiting" depending on which you use, and find many good articles.

I recently received a DDOS attack and they combined it with this Facebook attack method at the same time, the Facebook ASN AS32934, hit 1,060 URLs in 1 second.

I just banned the entire ASN, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [this](https://github.com/nadimtuhin/Facebook-Request-Throttle-WordPress-Plugin) WordPress plugin to limit the facebook crawler requests as I am hosting a news paper website and they definitely do **not** want block Facebook for marketing / sharing reasons.

Try it out!